# Do I have problems with heater

Tags: water-heater

There's only 15 minutes of hot water. I shut down cold side slowly to extend hot water and it turns hot water cold. What's wrong?

Comment: Electric water heater tank?

Comment: Size of tank and type added to your question will help us.

Comment: " I shut down cold side slowly to extend hot water and it turns hot water cold. " Maybe you're shutting down the hot side!

Comment: Maybe the faucet is incorrectly connected. Does it run hot when only the hot is turned on?

Comment: How old is this water heater? Has it always behaved like this? If not, how long did it behave differently or correctly? When it behaved correctly, how long did the hot water supply last?

Comment: the `dip tube` fell off

Comment: So "water-saving" showerheads are 1.5 GPM, so that means "normal" showerheads are 2 GPM or more.  2 GPM for 15 minutes uses 30 gallons, which will empty the common 30-gallon water heater.  3 GPM for 15 minutes empties a 45-gallon tank.  Water heaters don't make hot water *in real time*; that would be a tankless that takes like 100-150A of power.

Comment: Is  this 15 minutes full hot, or 15 minutes hot/cold shower mix?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that can cause you to have very little hot water. Without more detail it's hard to tell, but here are things it might be:

- Water heater isn't heating properly any more, and what little warm water you're getting is just from it warming up as it sits in the tank. Could be an electrical problem or issue with the heating element.
- Sediment buildup in the tank limiting the volume of water that can be heated, and building up around the heating elements so they don't heat efficiently. That build up can also cause the water heater to turn off before the water gets properly hot to prevent the element from overheating.
- Failing thermostatic mixing valve. It's common in some areas to see thermostatic mixing valves or anti scalding valves either at the output of the water tank or at point of use in showers and facets. These mix some cold water with the really hot water to prevent people from burning themselves. Sometimes they fail in a way that makes them either close off the hot, or open the cold too much as the valve warms up.

Comment: It sounds like the OP has hot water, but runs out after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an electric water heater with the only the upper element working. Being near the top it only heats the top strata of water, it is sometimes described as a fast recovery element.

The upper thermostat is a double throw switch (like a three-way). When temp is below set-point it powers the upper element. Once the small volume of water at the top is heated to set point the upper thermostat switches power from the upper element to the lower thermostat. The lower thermostat is a simple single pole (on-off) switch that feeds power to the lower element when water at the bottom is cold.

Somehow current isn't getting through the lower element. It could be a dirty contact in the upper stat, failed lower stat, failed lower element, or failed wire connecting any of the above.

Using a volt-ohm meter you can chase down the individual failed component and replace a single $15 part, but to me it's like replacing one tire at a time, and a kit that has both stats and elements often costs less than $40 on Amazon. Likely it's the lower element, elements require draining the tank, so it also makes some sense to replace both at once.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a *tanked* water heater (as opposed to a tankless).  Tanked heaters are not powerful enough to make hot water "on demand"; that would be a "tankless heater", and if you had one of those, you'd know it!

Tank heaters have a gallon capacity, the most common is 30 gallon.

Shower heads also have a flow rate between 1 and 3 gallons per minute.  1.5 GPM is considered "low flow".  So 2 GPM is a modest non-California showerhead.

Think about it.  30 gallon tank and the showerhead is 2 gallons per minute.  How long will that last.  **15 minutes**.  Working as advertised.

You might have a 45 gallon tank but a 3 GPM showerhead, same difference.

**15 minutes is a normal and expected run-time for a shower on a tanked heater**. If you don't like it, get a low-flow or ultra-low-flow showerhead, but you may not like those either.

Now what the British do, is they have an ultra-low-flow (0.7 to 1 gallon per minute) showerhead. By slowing the flow down *that much*, it becomes practical to have an "on-demand heater" dedicated to the shower. Takes about 9500W. (40A).  That means they never run out of hot water.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the capacity of the heater and the rate you're drawing water.  Many heaters (especially electric ones) will only provide hot water for 15 minutes or so at a high rate of flow.

But if an electric heater seems to run out of hot water too quickly this could be a sign that the lower heating element is burned out or the thermostat is failing.